# Stacked canvas elements, topmost canvas prevents events to reach the others

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, dom-events

I got three HTML5 canvas elements. One is transparent and completely covers the other two, that are not overlapping (What I draw on it must be superimposed, so its z-index must be the highest).

The problem is that the topmost one (`overlay_area`) prevents the other two receiving events. I don't need events to be received by the topmost one, so

- Is there a way to stop the topmost canvas receiving events?
- if not, is there a way to pass the events to the bottom canvases?

For this project, I need to use hammer.js and **no** jquery.

```
<canvas id="overlay_area"
        style="z-index: 8; position:absolute; left:0px; top:35px;"
        height="762px" width="968px">
        This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
        </canvas>

    <canvas id="wave_area"
        style="z-index: 5;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:35px;"
        height="762px" width="200px">
        This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
        </canvas>

    <canvas id="edit_area"
        style="z-index: 5;
        position:absolute;
        left:200px;
        top:35px;"
        height="762px" width="768px">
        This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a few ways to achieve this like Frederic points out in his answer. Another way to ignore mouse events on an element is to assign the following style.

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Its <s>well</s> decently supported and works great.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/D3jYZ/)**

So in your case it would be

```
<canvas id="overlay_area"
    style="z-index: 8; position:absolute; left:0px; top:35px; pointer-events:none;"
    height="762px" width="968px">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
```

Comment: Well, Internet Explorer and Opera [do not support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) `pointer-events`, so maybe *widely supported* is a little optimistic :)

Comment: Ah good point.. for some reason I thought IE8+ supported it. Opera meh.

Comment: THis solves my problem (I develop exclusively for Safari and Chrome at the moment, Web Audio stuff)

Comment: @janesconference yeah I figured if someones doing work with canvas they are using a pretty competent browser anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the three `<canvas>` elements into a parent element, then let the events bubble up to the parent and handle them there.

Using the [pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.pageX) and [pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.pageY) properties of the `event` object, in conjunction with the [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetLeft), [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop), [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth) and [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight) properties of your `<canvas>` elements, will allow you to translate the coordinates of mouse events and determine where they would have been triggered if they could have reached the bottom elements.